# Проект на c++ распознается github как будто 79% файлов- это SWIG

Tags: c++, github, swig

Решаю учебные задания на с++, оформляя их в проект. Пользуюсь Clion 2020.2 и cmake. Собираю и запускаю из IDE.

После того, как залил проект на github обнаружилось, что 78% файлов распознается, как SWIG. Погуглил, но не нашел решения такой проблемы.

[image: ![]

Скрин после нажатия на SWIG в информации о языках проекта из скрина выше прилагаю.

[image: ![]

Что делать, подскажите, пожалуйста!

UPD:

Сделал аналогично [stackoverflow.com/q/34713765/13970074](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713765/github-changes-repository-to-wrong-language), прописав в .gitattributes:

```
* linguist-vendored  
*.cpp linguist-vendored=false
```

Спасибо [dIm0n](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/398802/dim0n)!

Comment: Хм, действительно. Попробуйте почитать https://github.com/github/markup/issues/892 и связанные issues. И вот этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/q/34713765/13970074

Comment: @General, если нашли решение вашей проблемы, добавьте ответом (поле "Ваш ответ" ниже), добавлять ответ в вопрос здесь не принято.